# Changing rootViewController doesn't display viewController set as root

Tags: ios, swift, rootviewcontroller

I have an initialViewController, if I find user login information, I route user to Home, but if I don't, I set register/login ViewController as root. I tested with break points that my register/login ViewController didLoad and didAppear getting execute, but my register/login ViewController don't show and initialViewController remains on screen. this is my code:

```
public static func setRootViewController(withId id: String, storyBoardName: String) {
    let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: storyBoardName, bundle: nil)
    let newRootVC = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: id)
    appDelegateRef.window!.rootViewController = newRootVC
}
```

and this is part of my storyboard:

[image: part of my storyboard]

what's the problem here?

Comment: where are you calling `setRootViewController ` method?

Comment: I have a class with several static methods, I use 'static func logoutUser()' in initialViewController's willAppear and I call 'setRootViewController' in logoutUser.

Comment: Did `setRootViewController` called on main queue?

Comment: I moved logoutUser() call to viewDidAppear and it fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Put this function in your AppDelegate class. You can call this function from anywhere in your view controllers.

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
    // ...

    public func present(viewController: UIViewController) {
        guard let window = window else { return }
        UIView.transition(with: window, duration: 0.5, options: .transitionFlipFromLeft, animations: {
            window.rootViewController = viewController
        }, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

In the view controller you want the user to log out from, call the function above this way:

```
public static func setRootViewController(withId id: String, storyBoardName: String) {
    let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: storyBoardName, bundle: nil)
    let newRootVC = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: id)

    guard let delegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else { return }
    delegate.present(viewController: newRootVC)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use appDelegateRef.window!.makeKeyAndVisible() at end of your function

```
public static func setRootViewController(withId id: String, storyBoardName: String) {
    let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: storyBoardName, bundle: nil)
    let newRootVC = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: id)
    appDelegateRef.window!.rootViewController = newRootVC
    appDelegateRef.window!.makeKeyAndVisible()
}
```