# How to navigate to specific controller in navigation Controller

Tags: swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller, navigation, storyboard

I am trying to navigate the second controller from the storyboard but the navigation bar is not showing on a controller. Actually I want to show controller from app delegates.

Here is my stack :
[image]

here is my code:

```
             let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: AppStoryboards.MAIN, bundle: Bundle.main)

                guard let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: ViewControllerIdentifiers.THREAD_DETAIL_CONTROLLER) as? ThreadDetailController else {
                    return
                }

                controller.threadIdReceivedFromFeed = threadId as? String ?? String()

                self.window?.rootViewController = controller
```

here is actual result:

[image]

Comment: Maybe this answers can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53920649/changing-rootviewcontroller-doesnt-display-viewcontroller-set-as-root

Comment: Where are you writing this code?

Comment: Bcz i am showing view Controller from App Delegates

Answer (score 1):

You need to use add the `controller` as the `rootViewController` of the `UINavigationController` and then set that `navigationController` as `window's` `rootViewController`, i.e.

```
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: AppStoryboards.MAIN, bundle: nil)

    if let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: ViewControllerIdentifiers.THREAD_DETAIL_CONTROLLER) as? ThreadDetailController {
        controller.threadIdReceivedFromFeed = (threadId as? String) ?? ""
        let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: controller) //here...
        self.window?.rootViewController = navigationController
    }
```

Comment: Because there is nothing else in the navigationStack where you would move. `rootViewController` is the very first controller in the navigationStack.

Comment: Okay, now I have to move feed screen what should I do?

Comment: Please clarify the flow that you want to create and what all controllers do you want in that. Add in the question itself.

Comment: I opening detail of post know there is no back stack how to move the first Screen of navigation Controller

Comment: Instead of setting the `ThreadDetailController` as window's rootViewController, push it from the `FeedViewController`. Add the code for `FeedViewController` from where you want to show `ThreadDetailController`.